# Jquery validation custom validator firing too often

Tags: jquery

I have written a custom validator function for the jquery validation module.  It works correctly and performa the correct validation.

When you submit the form for the first time tbe validation function is called once on the submit. However once the form has discovered errors it appears to call the custom validation function (and the built in ones) on every keystroke.  How can I prevent this on my custom validator?  I only want it to be called when the user next clicks submit and not when they type in the corresponding text field

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are you checking validation on keyup?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit hidden in the documentation

See http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/  -  **onkeyup**

```
Example: Disables onkeyup validation.

$(".selector").validate({
  onkeyup: false
});
```